# Is $T = \dfrac{n(\bar X - X_{(1)})} {n-1}$ an unbiased and consistent estimator of $b$. Problem in mathematical statistics.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Good morning everybody! I am in an urgent need of help/leads (absolute 0 in math statistics).

1) A random variable has a Cumulative distribution function $F(x)=1-e^{-(x-a)/b}$, where $x > a$.

Is $T = \dfrac{n(\bar X - X_{(1)})} {n-1}$ an unbiased and consistent estimator of $b$.

2) Find the estimator $b$ by a method of Maximum Likelihood from problem 1. Compare the efficiency of estimators from both problems.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Difficult to help when there is no personal input whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer.** Here is a partial quick-and-dirty answer with minimal effort. The OP is invited to fill-in the blanks, and correct typos and thinkos...

---

The PDF of $X$ is $f(x) = F'(x)= (1/b)\exp(-(x-a)/b)1[\![x > a]\!]$ and it's mean is
$$
\mathbb E X = \int_{\mathbb R} xf(x)dx = \int_{a}^\infty (x/b)\exp(-(x-a)/b)dx = a + b
$$

$(A)$ Given an iid sample $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ from $F$, sort it so that $a < X_{(1)} \le X_{(2)} \le \ldots \le X_{(n)}$, and set $T_n := \dfrac{n(\overline{X}_n-X_{(1)})}{n-1}$. Note that $\overline{X}_n,X_{(1)},\ldots,X_{(n)},T_n$ are all random variables. As $n$ grows, $X_{(1)}$ will accumulate around $a$ on average (this can be made more formal if needed...), i.e $\mathbb E X_{(1)} \longrightarrow a$ in the limit as $n \longrightarrow \infty$. Let $\overline{X}_n = (1/n)\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ be the sample mean. Then $\mathbb E \overline{X}_n = \mathbb E X = a + b$, and  so 
$\mathbb E T_n = \dfrac{n(\mathbb E\overline{X}_n-\mathbb EX_{(1)})}{n-1} = \dfrac{n(a + b - \mathbb E X_{(1)})}{n-1} \longrightarrow \dfrac{nb}{n-1} \longrightarrow b$ in the limit as $n \longrightarrow \infty$.

> Thus $T_n$ is a consistent estimator for the parameter $b$.

*(B)* ***MLE estimation of $b$.*** The negative log-likelihood of the sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is
$$
\begin{split}
\ell_n(a,b) &:= -\sum_{i=1}^n \log f(X_i)=-\sum_{i=1}^n \log((1/b)\exp(-(X_i-a)/b)) \\
&= n\log b +\frac{1}{b}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-a) = n\log b + \frac{n}{b}(\overline{X}_n-a).
\end{split}
$$

Differentiating w.r.t to $b$ and setting to zero gives $0 = \dfrac{\partial \ell_n(a,b)}{\partial b} = \dfrac{n}{b}-\dfrac{n(\bar{X}_n-a)}{b^2}$, from which $b=\hat{b} = \overline{X}_n-a$.
Moreover,

> $\hat{b}$ consistently estimates the parameter $b$ since $\mathbb E \hat{b} = \mathbb E \overline{X}_n - a = a+b - a = b$.

Comment: Thank you so much @dohmatob for a swift reply! As I am trying to understand your marvelous solution, I have a couple of questions: 
Is it necessary to find an "asymptotic unbiased estimator" rather than just "unbiased estimator"?
Thank you!